# Android ImageView's ScaleType impacts on Performance and Memory

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

Does the scaleType I choose for my ImageView have an impact on "performance" and memory footprint? Which one is the best solution considering performance and memory?

If I choose centerCrop as scaleType, which memory footprint do I have in addition to the original picture? Is it possible to say this? Is fitXY "better"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes I noticed a massive drop in UI responsiveness when using centerCrop as opposed to the default scaleType for a screen with only 4 images on it.  However, I was using Univeral Image Loader library to display these images, and I had the imageScaleType property set to EXACTLY_STRETCHED ion the display options.  Once I removed this, performance was ok still using centerCrop on the ImageView control.  So it seems that some ImageView.scaleType values can cause performance issues at least when used in combination with UIL.